# Python: как вывести число типа float с определенным количеством знаков после запятой

Tags: python, float

Есть вот такая функция:

```
def vol(rad):

    print(4/3*3.141592*rad**3, "cm^3")
```

вывод будет:

```
vol(5)

523.5986666666666 cm^3
```

Вопрос: как вывести ответ определенным количеством знаков после запятой, напирмер 523.598 или 523.59 по возможности сохранив компактность кода

Comment: а почему не 523.599 или 523.60 ?

Comment: можно и так, суть в сокращении числа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, используя строковый метод [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=format#str.format):

```
>>> "{0:.2f}".format(70.12312312)
'70.12'
```

Там есть много опций, для форматирования вывода, можно подробнее почитать в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

В вашем случае нужно в функции выводить в `print` не числа, а строку с форматированием, например:

```
>>> def vol(rad):
....    print("{0:.2f} cm^3".format(4/3*3.141592*rad**3))

>>> vol(5)
523.60 cm^3
```

Еще интересные способы форматирования есть на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python). Там немного другой вывод хотел получить автор, но можно подглядеть именно способ.

Answer (score 3):

Такой вариант устроит?

```
rad = 5
print(4/3*3.141592*rad**3, "cm^3")
#523.5986666666666 cm^3

print("{0:.4f} cm^3".format(4/3*3.141592*rad**3))
#523.5987 cm^3
```

Либо через f-strings, которые побыстрее будут:

```
res = 4/3*3.141592*rad**3
print(f'{res:.4f} cm^3')
#523.5987 cm^3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def vol(rad, f):
    print("{:.{}f} {}".format(4/3*3.141592*rad**3, f, "cm^3"))


vol(5, 3)
523.599 cm^3

vol(5, 2)
523.60 cm^3
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть специальная функция `round`

```
x = 4.4444
print(round(x, 2))    # 4.44
```